# set focus on a particular form in Access 2007

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2007

I have multiple forms in access, How can I set focus on a "Form1" on load event of "Form2"?

I tried the below method, but it doesn't work. The focus is still on "Form2"

```
Private Sub Form_Load()
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
Forms!Form1.SetFocus
End Sub
```

I have selected "Form2" in "Display Form:" option in "Access Options", I am opening "Form1" in "Form2" Load event and then trying to set focus to "Form1"

Thanks in advance

Comment: Have you thought about doing it the other way around? Opening Form2 instead of Form1 thus not needing to switch the focus?

Comment: Further information why this is happening: [www.simply-access.com/Form-Events.html](http://www.simply-access.com/Form-Events.html)

Answer (score 1):

Changed :

I think the only solution is to open the form as a dialog :

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1" ', , , , , acDialog
```

try it, it worked for me

Comment: That won't work because the opened form gets its focus after the load Event. You technically switch the focus, but it gets right back to form2.

Answer (score 0):

Try this :

```
Private Sub Form_Activate()
  DoCmd.OpenForm "Form1"
  Forms!Form1.SetFocus
End Sub
```